# Does passing series to df_lenght results in TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__

Tags: python, python-3.x

While working on a data exploration task I've faced this issue where I'm unable to format a float value into a percentage using the format string as below:

```
     # Exploring views taken
    total_ap = all_xray_df['View Position'][all_xray_df['View Position'] == 'AP']\
                                          .value_counts()
    total_pa = all_xray_df['View Position'][all_xray_df['View Position'] == 'PA']\
                                          .value_counts()
    print("Total number of views taken: {}\n".format(df_length))
    print("Total number of AP views taken: {}\n".format(total_ap))
    print("Total number of PA views taken: {}\n".format(total_pa))
    print("% of AP views: {0}, {1:.2%}\n".format(total_ap, total_ap/df_length))
    print("% of PA views: {0}, {1:.2%}\n".format(total_pa, total_pa/df_length))
```

The output of which is:

```
Total number of views taken: 112120

Total number of AP views taken: AP    44810
Name: View Position, dtype: int64

Total number of PA views taken: PA    67310
Name: View Position, dtype: int64

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-c2c624bf15b5> in <module>
      7 print("Total number of AP views taken: {}\n".format(total_ap))
      8 print("Total number of PA views taken: {}\n".format(total_pa))
----> 9 print("% of AP views: {0}, {1:.2%}\n".format(total_ap, total_ap/df_length))
     10 print("% of PA views: {0}, {1:.2%}\n".format(total_pa, total_pa/df_length))

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__
```

Comment: `total_ap/df_length` is a pandas `Series` object. You need to pass single value not Series. The quick fix can be `print(*["% of AP views: {0}, {1:.2%}\n".format(total_ap, i) for i in total_ap/df_length])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that Pandas' `value_counts()` returns a series. By using the shape property of the dataframe I was able to correct this as below:

```
    total_ap = all_xray_df['View Position'][all_xray_df['View Position'] == 'AP']\
                                          .shape[0]
    total_pa = all_xray_df['View Position'][all_xray_df['View Position'] == 'PA']\
                                          .shape[0]
```